# tree view menu is not expanding while on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With the following code, I am trying to fix the menu where the class of active is not getting implemented

here is the jsfiddle

> https://jsfiddle.net/rbj7ad1m/

```
var action = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];

// If there's no action, highlight the first menu item
if (action == "") {
    $('ul.treeview-menu li:first').addClass('active');
} else {
    // Highlight current menu
    $('ul.treeview-menu a[href="/' + action + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

    // Highlight parent menu item
    $('ul.treeview-menu a[href="/' + action + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
}
```

it is not the complete menu, but i had added the JSCode to make sure it work, but somehow it is not working, can someone jump in and see if i am doing anything with the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot to add the jQuery library into your fiddle.

I've had a look at your code and you are trying to compare `action` with 
 this `""`, when the actual value is `"_display"`.

So the following code is working fine:

```js
   //$('ul.treeview-menu:first').addClass('active');
var action = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
// If there's no action, highlight the first menu item
if (action == "_display") {
    $('ul.treeview-menu li:first').addClass('active');
} else {
    // Highlight current menu
    $('ul.treeview-menu a[href="/' + action + '"]').parent().addClass('active');

    // Highlight parent menu item
    $('ul.treeview-menu a[href="/' + action + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: my url is like : `http://example.com/sections/page1?id=1&p=10.` So i checked the code and if i pass the action to pick item `[2] `instead of `1`, it seems to be picking the action value which in the above case comes as:` "page1"`, but it never keeps the selected value active, i had removed the a `href=/` which is not required i think,